# How can I select all user with same column value (php)

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

here is my prob. :

I got a users table with a column "music_style" who get value from a select input

example : rock, metal, pop,...

I want to select all other users who have the same "music_style" as me.

Example : If I put "metal" on my profile, i want to see all other profile with metal.

I hope to have been clear, sorry for my bad english :s

Comment: Show code, try before ask, it's the base of php-mysql i can't believe you can't find some help on internet to start . Please make some effort to provide a beginning of work and then we can help you

Comment: your English is good, the lack of code is bad ;)

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using an sql based dbms, you may use the following sql statement:

```
 SELECT * FROM `USERSTABLE` WHERE `music_style` = '$myStyle';
```

`$myStyle` is the php variable where you are storing the input.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, it work perfectly. But it select all user with the same music_style, including me. I tried to correct this but it didn't work .

I tried this :

```
 $id = $_GET['id']

("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `music_style` = '$myStyle' AND 'id' != '$id' ");
```